# Filepicker.io Javascript API Remove

Tags: filepicker.io

Trying to use the remove function after the pick function and file is not being removed. (from here  https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file_ingestion/javascript_api/remove?v=v2)

```
 selectFileMedium: function () {
     filepicker.pick({
                cropRatio: 24/13,
                mimetype: 'image/*',
                imageDim: [1440, 780]
            }, function (Blob) {
                InnerThis.uploadMediumImage(Blob.url, Blob.filename);
                filepicker.remove(Blob);
            });
}
```

Am I doing this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blob object return url property which is unificated url of uploaded file eg:

```
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/AQgF2U68SNmJDpDXlOdg
```

However since v2 dialog version there is crop UI avaliable. If user crop file as a response it return the uploaded file url with appended Rest convert parameters:

```
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/AQgF2U68SNmJDpDXlOdg/convert?crop=100,200,200,300
```

filepicker.remove dose not deal with it. Some temporary workaround would be to strip url from '/convert' part just before remove it. However it should be solved on library side.

Comment: For other reasons I had to take this back out but this is the reason it was not working